# Dependency Injection failed in spring boot , maven based multiple modules project

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi friends i am developing a maven based spring boot project project , this project is multiple module form one module is **Main** module and second module is **Service** Module. I have one controller in Main module and one service in Serivce module

**Controller**

```
package com.aquevix.controller;

import com.aquevix.common.MyService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * Created by mohdqasim on 11/9/15.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @Inject MyService myService;
    @Inject BookRepository bookRepository;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData(){
     return myService.getData();
    }
}
```

Service

```
package com.aquevix.common;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * Created by mohdqasim on 11/9/15.
 */
@Service
public class MyService {
    public String getData(){
        return "hello qasim";
    }
}
```

In maven multiple modules this scenerio is working fine but i have also one repository in the form of interface in service module.

```
package com.aquevix.common;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;

/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Book entity.
 */
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {

}
```

So when i execute main class from **Main** module my project works fine without bookrepository in **service** module( or present in Main module) but if i put bookrepository in **Service** module then MyController could not instantiate due dependency injection failure of bookRepository in MyController.
Can anyone help me how to to avoid this failure i put any interface in **Service** module which is being injected into **Main** module

Comment: Could you show your Application class? And second question - are you changing package of repository while relocation it to **service** module?

Comment: I had similar issue with a multi module Spring Boot project where my Mongo Repositories were in different project. Tried adding as Dependency Project in Eclipse too and it didn't work. It threw error referring cglib. Had to convert to Java Standalone application to get this working.

Comment: Show your main Spring app class and show the package structure.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to JavaConfig your repository location like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.aquevix.common")
class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    // …
  }
}
```

More reference at [Working with Spring Data Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

Comment: This configuration isn't needed with Spring Boot. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql) part of the documentation

Comment: Thnx for replying , what if my custom interface do not extend jpa repository and i want to create bean on fly

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it using this post: [Spring Boot: autowire beans from library project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816619/5571772)

In short, add this annotation to your application:

```
@Import(SharedConfigurationReference.class)
```

And then in your Service project create the `SharedConfigurationReference` class

```
package com.aquevix.common;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.aquevix")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.aquevix")
@EntityScan("com.aquevix")
public class SharedConfigurationReference {}
```

For the entity and component scan annotations, make sure to specify a package that is **parent** to all your projects, i.e. parent to controller and service