# Spring dependency injection in a non-spring boot application

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I writing a library which doesn't have a `main` and isn't a `Spring Boot` application but I'd still like to use Spring Framework's dependency injection to load the dependencies of my classes. I'd like this library to be available to everyone, even developers who aren't going to be using Spring.

Is there a way for me to take advantage of Spring Framework's dependency injection even if the users of my library won't be using Spring?

Currently I'm importing my library into another one of my apps but my dependencies are turning out as `null`. Is there a way to get around this?

```
@Component
public class Client
{
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService; // this is null


    public static Client createClientWithCredentials(String clientId, String clientSecret)
    {
        return new Client(clientId, clientSecret);
    }

    private Client(String clientId, String clientSecret)
    {
         // ...
    }
}

@Service
public class ClientService {
    // ...
}
```

Someone using my library would use instantiate it like this.

```
...
// Non-Spring project

Client client = Client.createClientWithCredentials("id", "secret");
...
```

Unfortunately using `client` will at some point throw a `NullPointerException` since `clientService` is `null`. I'm also testing my app this way and this is why I know that I have `null` dependencies.

How can I take advantage of Spring's Dependency Injection if my app is never run but only used as a library?

Is this possible or do I need to use the old way of every class constructing it's own dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot: autowire beans from library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815871/spring-boot-autowire-beans-from-library-project)

Comment: @lakshman I think it does! I will have to check later tonight when I get home!

Comment: does this work when the library is being used by a non-spring app

Comment: @lakshman I updated my question to make it unique from the one you provided