# Spring : autoconfigured bean in dependency library is not loaded in Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on some Java projects using Spring boot. I have an autoconfigured class `MyAutoConfig` in the `spring.factories` file in a project `A`.

This configuration file has some bean definitions, for example the class `Worker`.

The project `B` is using `A` as a library, in gradle like this:

```
implementation project(':project-A')
```

I can start project `B` without any errors. But when I try to use `@Autowired Worker worker` in project `B` in the main class where I have `@SpringBootConfiguration`, it told me that `"expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate"`, so I assume that the bean is not in the context.

I would like to know what could be the problem ?

Comment: hmm, what if you build the jar and try to start it up via `java -jar`? In case this does not work either, you could unpack the jar and look what is actually inside it, that could shed some light.

Comment: what should I look for ? You mean in the jar of project B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SpringBootConfiguration` is not enough for the auto-configuration. You should add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. This will trigger scanning `spring.factories` files and do the rest for you.

Or using `@SpringBootApplication`, because it has `EnableAutoConfiguration` in it.

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = {@Filter(
    type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
    classes = {TypeExcludeFilter.class}
), @Filter(
    type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
    classes = {AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class}
)}
)
public @interface SpringBootApplication
```