# Spring bean not getting Autowired from custom library

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created by own library(com.custom.mylib) which returns a string like below.

```
@Component
public class MyLibrary{

    @Value("${str.message}")
    private String message; //This val should come from app which is going to use this lib
    public String readMessage() {
        return message;
    }
```

I have create a project which is going to use above library. I have included  the lib as pom dependency .But when I  try to call library method from my app. I get the error below.
How to resolve it?

```
   @Autowired
    private MyLibrary myLibrary;
```

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.custom.mylog.MyLibrary' in your
> configuration.

I also have below in application.properties file so that library can pick the value up

```
str.message=Hello world
```

Comment: can you share your `@Configuration` class? do you component-scan the relevant package?

Comment: I don't have any `@Configuration` class in the app(which is using library) .Its simple app trying to inject the component `Mylibrary`.Main app uses `@SpringBootApplication`.Am i missing something?

Comment: @NirLevyI got the solution it seems.I need to create META-INF file and do `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=<fully_qualified_name_of_configuration_file>` as given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815871/spring-boot-autowire-beans-from-library-project

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution it seems.I need to create META-INF file and do `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=<fully_qualified_name_of_configuration_file>`

as given here
[Spring Boot: autowire beans from library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815871/spring-boot-autowire-beans-from-library-project)

Answer (score 0):

As it has to be used as a external library, you can instantiate it throught a `@Configuration` file:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyLibrary createMyLibraryInstance() {
        return new MyLibrary();
    }
}
```

The rule I used is the follow (this is not an universal rule):

- In your domain classes (Controller, Service) : use `@Autowired` in your constructor. It is the recommanded way to inject your dependencies.
- You want to use external classes : implements a Java Configuration with `@Configuration` annotation, to instanciate your external classes as beans.
- You want to create custom utilities classes : decorate it with `@Component`.
- When you have more than on implementation, use `@Qualifier` and define your beans in a `@Configuration` class.